# asp.net routing on homepage

Tags: asp.net, routes, webforms

When using routing (asp.net webforms) I want to setup a home route so I can browse articles on the frontpage like this

domain.com
domain.com/1
domain.com/2
domain.com/3

I have no idea how to setup this routing because ~/ isn't accepted in the route. I tried http://www.domain.com/home/1 which works fine but is less nice ofcourse.

When I do it like this it work's fine but not on the homepage because it's looking for a pageindex which is ofcourse 'Default.aspx':

```
            routes.Add(
            "Home",
            new Route("{PageIndex}", new review.Routing.HomeRouteHandler())
        );
```

Any ideas on this, maybe im missing something here!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a trailing slash instead (It works for me anyway)

```
routes.Add(
            "Home",
            new Route("{PageIndex}/", new review.Routing.HomeRouteHandler())
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about ASP.NET routing, but this article may help:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/12/15/redirect-routes-and-other-fun-with-routing-and-lambdas.aspx